# Google App Engine (Python 2.7) Win 10 ImportError: No module named appengine.api

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I have a problem trying to run a python project, I already installed Python 2.7 and Google Cloud SDK (I followed up the instructions in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python), but I get the following error:

[ImportError: No module named appengine.api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ob5f.png)

Also I set up the enviroment variables:

[Enviromental variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekac2.png)

[Windows Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bpyL.png)

My OS is Windows 10

Comment: Where are you running the application? In App Engine (production) or in the Local Development server?

Comment: In the Local Development server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute the project in local, you would get that  error(google.appengine.api error). Basically it has to be executed on a server.

The server can be started using your terminal.

1) Go to the project path(root folder of all files in the project,eg: appengine)
2) start the server using $ dev_appserver.py app.yaml. It starts server at localhost port 8000 as the default one.
3) In the server start depends on the handler and its path specified (like '/' or '/testjob') try localhost:8000/ or localhost:8000/testjob
4) All the logs written in the program will be shown in the terminal. For logs try using 'logging' module , make sure to mention the logging level else basic level logs are not shown